# how to print date and time in one line in bash script?

Tags: scripting, date

I have tried following code

```
echo -n "Date :"
date +'%d/%m/%Y'
```

But I need it as following format

```
Date : 13/03/2018 Time : 11.30.30
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ date +"Date : %d/%m/%Y Time : %H.%M.%S"
Date : 13/03/2018 Time : 23.10.19
```